# web scraping with a button "show more"

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I need to extract articles from this website including title, date and URL.

https://en.news-front.info/category/ukraine-2/

I'm using the `rvest` package but I'm having difficulty extracting them due to the presence of the "**show more**" button that loads the other articles. How do I go about doing this? I need the articles through March 2021.

Thank you

Comment: This is not really an answer but as a pointer, you could try to use RSelenium instead of Rvest. It's more difficult to set up but basically allows you to navigate a website like you would as a human. You could use it to navigate to the page, click the button and then get the data you want (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51887807/click-button-via-rselenium)

Comment: Please share more details, like your attempts to resolve the problem. Anything not working when you click the "show more" button in your scraper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct solution for extracting articles with the button "show more"

```
library(RSelenium)
rD1 <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", port = 4567L, geckover = NULL, 
            chromever =  "99.0.4844.51", iedrver = NULL, 
            phantomver = NULL)
remDr1 <- rD1[["client"]] 
remDr1$navigate("https://en.news-front.info/category/ukraine-2/")

webElem <- remDr1$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".btn-load-more")
webElem$clickElement()

replicate(50,
      {
        # find button
        morereviews <- remDr1$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".btn-load-more")
        # click button
        morereviews$clickElement()
        # wait
        Sys.sleep(2)
      })

# Scrap the reviews
title <- xml2::read_html(remDr1$getPageSource()[[1]])%>%
rvest::html_nodes(".article-link__title") %>%
rvest::html_text() %>%
dplyr::data_frame(title = .)
title
```

Comment: Please share more details such that others can learn form your answer. What did you change?

Comment: It's unclear what question you're answering, as your original question had nothing specific, just a high-level requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try before harvesting data:

```
webElem <- remDr$findElement(using = 'css selector', ".btn-load-more")
webElem$clickElement()
```

after this chunk (not sure if neccessary, unfortunetaly you didn't provide any code)

```
Sys.sleep(2)
```

```
YOUR HARVESTING CODE
```